# Scrapy not working on OBD site

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy-spider on oneblockdown.it to get all the products from the latest products and to store them into a DB.

Some sites into my monitor are working, but someone such as OBD is not working and not uploading nothing to the db. This is my function:

```
class OneBlockDownSpider(Spider):

name = "OneBlockDownSpider"
allowded_domains = ["oneblockdown.it"]
start_urls = [OneBlockDownURL]

def __init__(self):
    logging.critical("OneBlockDown STARTED.")

def parse(self, response):
    products = Selector(response).xpath("//div[@id='product-list']")

    for product in products:
        item = OneBlockDownItem()
        item['name'] = product.xpath('.//div[@class="catalogue-product-title"]//h3').extract.first
        item['link'] = product.xpath('.//div[@class="catalogue-product-title"]//h3/a/@href').extract.first
        # # item['image'] = "http:" + product.xpath("/div[@class='catalogue-product-cover']/a[@class='catalogue-product-cover-image']/img/@src").extract()[0]
        # item['size'] = '**NOT SUPPORTED YET**'
        yield item

    yield Request(OneBlockDownURL, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True, priority=15)
```

I guess I'm using the wrong xpath, but I can't solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **the site is Cloudflare protected** (prevent scraping).

Also you have several issues with your code:

1. Your `products` is a single node
2. You're using `extract.first` instead of `extract_first()`

   ```
   products = response.xpath("//div[@id='product-list']/div")

   for product in products:
       item = OneBlockDownItem()
       item['name'] = product.xpath('.//div[@class="catalogue-product-title"]//h3').extract_first()
       item['link'] = product.xpath('.//div[@class="catalogue-product-title"]//h3/a/@href').extract_first()
       yield item
   ```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to bypass the scape block on OBD?

Comment: @traiantomescu First you'll need to support Javascript in your code to bypass it

Comment: I think I will need to, but not my code so I need to learn how it works, how can I start with the implementation?

Comment: @traiantomescu I recommend you to start with Google query "How to bypass Cloudflare"

Answer (score 0):

You should start all your xpaths with `'.'` when using a relative selector like product:

```
item['image'] = "http:" + product.xpath("./div[@class='catalogue-product-cover']/a[@class='catalogue-product-cover-image']/img/@src").extract()[0]
```

Otherwise, It will try to get the element with this xpath: `/body/div[@class='catalogue-product-cover']`